# How can a result of a query be returned as JSON? Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, nativequery

I have a method that should output me a JSON from a desired table. To keep the service as flexible as possible, I decided to use native queries, not to use entities and also to work without repositories. But so that I don't just get a list of objects from the database like this statement "final String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + schemaName + "." + tableName;", I extended my SQL statement with array_to_json. This is how I get a JSON from my DB.

Here is my method:

```
    @Override
    public List<Map<String, Object>> getList(String tableName, String schemaName) {
        // final String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + schemaName + "." + tableName;
        final String sql = "SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(" + tableName + ")) FROM " + schemaName + "." + tableName;
        final Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
        
        final List<Map<String, Object>> queryResult = query.;
        return queryResult;
    }
```

When I execute my sql statement in the PG Admin then I get the following JSON:

```
[{"id":1,"analytic_id":1,"propertytype":"shape","min_val":null,"max_val":null,"string_val":"102941","case_else":0,"result":"kugel"},{"id":2,"analytic_id":1,"propertytype":"shape","min_val":null,"max_val":null,"string_val":"019283","case_else":0,"result":"rechteck"},{"id":3,"analytic_id":1,"propertytype":"shape","min_val":null,"max_val":null,"string_val":"0122343","case_else":0,"result":"prism"},{"id":6,"analytic_id":1,"propertytype":"color","min_val":0,"max_val":20,"string_val":null,"case_else":0,"result":"grun"},{"id":7,"analytic_id":1,"propertytype":"color","min_val":21,"max_val":50,"string_val":null,"case_else":0,"result":"gelb"},{"id":8,"analytic_id":1,"propertytype":"color","min_val":51,"max_val":80,"string_val":null,"case_else":0,"result":"hellblau"},{"id":9,"analytic_id":1,"propertytype":"color","min_val":81,"max_val":999,"string_val":null,"case_else":0,"result":"rot"},{"id":10,"analytic_id":1,"propertytype":"color","min_val":null,"max_val":null,"string_val":null,"case_else":1,"result":"lila"}]
```

Now for my question:
So I get a JSON from my query. But how do I rebuild my method so that I can display the result of my query in the GetRequest. It is important to me that I get a JSON with all data back and that the return type is compatible with OPENAPI 3.0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use this tutorial as a starting point: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this is not what I need. As mentioned above, I want my service to work without connecting to any entity or repository. It's just that I want to return the result of my query in my service.

Comment: The tutorial shows how to output JSON from a REST-endpoint. Use the necessary parts in the tutorial to do that. One way is to store the result from a query to a POJO in a List<> and have the REST-enpoint return it as JSON.